# AngularJS extract <img> from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

How can I extract certain tag, for example img when parsing JSON in AngularJS? 
I have a JSON file with following data:

```
jsonFeed({
"title": "My Blog",
"items": [
   {
      "title": "Title1",
      "description": "<p><a href=\"#">Paul<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p><img src=\"https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7365/26872407641_cfbb210ee7_m.jpg\"/>"
   },
   {
      "title": "Title2",
      "description": "<p><a href=\"#">Beth<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p><img src=\"https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7287/26333398074_cfbce73532_m.jpg\"/>"
   }
   ]
 });
```

I need to get that image in description for every post:

```
<article ng-repeat="post in posts">
  <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
  <img src=""/>
</article>
```

Is there way to do that in angularjs or is it better to use jQuery?

Comment: use substring and indexof method to get the img tag from description. use angular $sanitize to show html

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can use `regex`:  `((?:http|https)(?::\\/{2}[\\w]+)(?:[\\/|\\.]?)(?:[^\\s"]*))`</strike>

You can use $sce to bind the HTML:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope", "$sce",
    function($scope, $sce) {
        $scope.jsonStr = {
            "title": "My Blog",
            "items": [{
                "title": "Title1",
                "description": "<p><a href=\"#\">Paul<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p><img src=\"https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7365/26872407641_cfbb210ee7_m.jpg\"/>"
            }, {
                "title": "Title2",
                "description": "<p><a href=\"#\">Beth<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p><img src=\"https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7287/26333398074_cfbce73532_m.jpg\"/>"
            }]
        }
        
        $scope.trustHtml = function(desc) {
         return $sce.trustAsHtml(desc);
        }
        
    }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  
  <h1>{{jsonStr.title}}</h1>
  
  <div ng-repeat="post in jsonStr.items">
    <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
    <div ng-bind-html="trustHtml(post.description)" />
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Here I need to extract only <img> tag not the whole description, previous version of answer was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Use jqLite, use `angular.element(post.description)[0].querySelector('img');` in your link function (if you are using a directive), or where ever angular.element is available to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $limitTo filter with a negative value for get the tag and then $sanitize for render it as html.

Read the next docs:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS comes with jqLite, called with `angular.element()`

```
obj['items'].forEach(function(val, i){
  var elm = angular.element(val['description'])[1].src;
  console.log(elm);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How I would do it:

- Loop over each item
- Use regex to get the img url (e.g. `\<img src=\\\"(.+)\\\"`)
- add the image url (`imgUrl` in this example) to each item.

Then in your html use it like this:

```
<article ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    <img ng-src="{{ post.imgUrl }}"/>
</article>
```

Notes

- I used [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc), not src
- The regex is only a quick sample